# Wrong database user

Tags: database

Maybe I've been staring at this too long and am missing something obvious. I do this duplicating of the live site onto the dev site often, but today it's broken.

I created a copy of our site. It's on Drupal 7 and CiviRM 4.7.22. I can log into the site and visit CiviCRM. When I try to register for an event, it fails with errors. I turned on all the error reporting. It shows it is failing because it is using the wrong database user - it's trying to use the database user for the live site instead of this dev one. Everything is correct in the settings file - it links to the right database user. So where else should I be looking to find a place where it is looking at the wrong database user? Thanks!

UPDATE: Well, I ran an update to 4.7.30 and now it's fixed.

Comment: You mentioned 'settings file' but didn't specifically say both settings.php and civicrm.settings.php (assuming both would require such a change)

Comment: Both are correct, as they are the original files (I don't copy over those from the live site). I checked them anyway just to make sure, but both are correct. Whatever it was somehow cleared up in the update.

Comment: maybe it needed caches clearing which the upgrade takes care of?

Comment: I must've cleared the cache more than a dozen times. So unless the button telling it to clear the cache isn't working, it's hard to believe it's that.

Answer (score 1):

While this is an older thread I recently found myself in the exact same situation. (We copied live to dev and couldn't update anything - the wrong database user error kept popping up.)

Turns out that while the settings file database user was correct, the triggers in the database still had a reference to the live database user (the trigger definer). While I'm exploring if there's a way to update those trigger definers - I assume that in your case running a database upgrade did that for you.

EDIT: (thanks to Demerit) to fix the wrong database user, I rebuilt the database triggers using the Civi URL command and all is good.

Comment: Try this https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#trigger-rebuild

Comment: OMG @demerit you are a life-saver. I didn't know it was that easy, I was scouring mysql references to try and do it.

Comment: Cool. It seems to come up once in a while. I will add it to a rainy-day todo list to make a system status check that checks if the trigger definer is different than the civicrm.settings.php user and then points you to the rebuild link.